# DataInputStream closing

Tags: java, inputstream

When I pass a InputStream to this method,
does it close that?

```
public void foo(InputStream is) {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
    dis.close();
}
```

The superclass FilterInputStream redefines the close method as closing underlying inputstream too, so it will close the parameter **is**.

Does that action affect the inputstream at the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the stream that is passed in will be closed.

Closing streams that you didn't open is hardly ever a good idea, so you should not close `dis` in this method.

`DataInputStream` holds no system resources of its own, so not closing it will not cause any leaks. You can simply leave it open. Alternatively you can return it from the method so that the caller can close it.

Comment: is it closed because it is passed as reference value to the method ?
and is it possible to "duplicate" a stream object?

Comment: So is there a way to close the dis "only"?

Comment: `DataInputStream` only provides a few convenient methods to read from the wrapped stream. Closing it "only" has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `DataInputStream` is a decorator-class over passed `InputStream` `is`. It isn't a `InputStream` it self.

So Essentially `DataInputStream.close` implies `close` on underlying `InputStream`.

`/**
     * Closes this input stream and releases any system resources
     * associated with the stream.
     * This
     * method simply performs <code>in.close()</code>.
     *
     * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
     * @see        java.io.FilterInputStream#in
     */
    public void close() throws IOException {
        in.close();
    }`

Answer (score 1):

The InputStream will be closed.

Since Java SE 7 it is better to use try-with-resources so streams will be closed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should close the InputStream in caller method only. Use Try Catch block whenever you are using any operation related to input or output streaming, if any of the stream remains open it will be handled by java

Answer (score 0):

The class `DataInputStream` implements `Coseable` and `AutoClose` interfaces so the method `close` in class `DataInputStream` closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream. This method simply performs `in.close()`.
Specified by close in interface `Closeable`, close in interface `AutoCloseable` Overrides close in class `InputStream`.

Throws:
`IOException` - if an I/O error occurs.